# Is it possible to Automate Windows Set up on Hyper-V using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I wanna know if that it's possible. I can create a new VM and start it but I don't know if the configuration of Windows can be automatize by a Powershell script.

Comment: To properly automate Windows installs you'd use Answer files and sysprep, not PowerShell.  After Windows is installed on a working VM, it's just another machine, you can configure it with PowerShell (or whatever) just like you would any other machine.  As-is this is too broad, and makes little sense.

Comment: You're question is very confusing.  You're either asking if you can configure a VM or whether you can script the host computer to create a guest instance.  In either case the answer is yes.

Answer (score -1):

Check your system to see a list of Hyper-V related cmdlets with:

```
PS C:\> Get-Command –Module Hyper-V
```

Your system might return no results to this command. The reason is that though you've installed the Hyper-V role, the Hyper-V PowerShell module didn't install. To install the module, you have to import it separately.

First, load the ServerManager Module:

```
PS C:\> Import-Module ServerManager
```

Respond to the security warning, if presented, by typing 'R'  to proceed with loading the ServerManager module.

Then, load the Hyper-V PowerShell Module located in the Remote Server Administration Tools feature.

```
PS C:\> Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-Hyper-V-Tools –IncludeAllSubFeature
```

After a few minutes you'll receive the system response that the installation was successful and that no restart (reboot) is needed.

Comment: The question owner wants to create a new VM in Hyper-V, not set up Hyper-V.